# How to POST Powershell output in Django?

Tags: python, django, powershell

I am currently working on a small Django project. I have written some powershell scripts  for e.g. get active directory users and want to setup a Django app which allows me to post the output from my powershell script

this is my cmdlet and output -

Command -

```
Get-OrgUser -eNumber 123456
```

Output -

```
FullName               : Surname, Firstname
eNumber                : 123456
PasswordExpired        : False
LastBadPasswordAttempt : 10/01/2019 12:16:28
LastLogonDate          : 13/02/2019 12:59:58
LockedOut              : UnLocked
LockoutTime            : 0
PasswordLastSet        : 17/01/2019 11:52:49
```

My Django app should allow user to input the employee number and show the results that it gets back from Powershell command.

Comment: Your question is too broad in its current form; please read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

n.b.., what you're trying to do is not recommended since your django server would have to be running as a user that had privileges to run commands that can access your active directory.  Normally, because your web server is available to certain users, you want to isolate it by creating a specific app user.  That said, once you have your scripts ready and in your django project, you can just use ordinary python to run your scripts and return the results in django using a standard view:

```
def my_view(request):
    import subprocess
    handle = subprocess.Popen([
        'powershell.exe',
        'script.ps1',
    ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
    output = handle.stdout.read().decode('utf-8')
    return HttpResponse(output)
```

In any case, the general rules about powershell apply here.  Your scripts must be signed if your server has an `ExecutionPolicy` set, otherwise you will have to update the `ExecutionPolicy` on the server to allow unsigned scripts to run.  The user that is running your django server is the one that will be calling the scripts and should have permissions necessary to carry out your scripts' commands.